# Is there a way to rank some items in a pandas dataframe and exclude others?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, ranking

I have a pandas dataframe called ranks with my clusters and their key metrics. I rank them them using `rank()` however there are two specific clusters which I want ranked differently to the others.

```py
ranks = pd.DataFrame(data={'Cluster': ['0', '1', '2',
                                   '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9'],
                        'No. Customers': [145118, 
                                        2, 
                                        1236, 
                                        219847, 
                                        9837,
                                        64865,
                                        3855,
                                        219549,
                                        34171,
                                        3924120],  
                        'Ave. Recency': [39.0197, 
                                        47.0, 
                                        15.9716, 
                                        41.9736, 
                                        23.9330,
                                        24.8281,
                                        26.5647,
                                        17.7493,
                                        23.5205,
                                        24.7933],
                        'Ave. Frequency': [1.7264, 
                                        19.0, 
                                        24.9101, 
                                        3.0682, 
                                        3.2735,
                                        1.8599,
                                        3.9304,
                                        3.3356,
                                        9.1703,
                                        1.1684],
                        'Ave. Monetary': [14971.85, 
                                        237270.00, 
                                        126992.79, 
                                        17701.64, 
                                        172642.35,
                                        13159.21,
                                        54333.56,
                                        17570.67,
                                        42136.68,
                                        4754.76]})
ranks['Ave. Spend'] = ranks['Ave. Monetary']/ranks['Ave. Frequency']
```

```
   Cluster   No. Customers| Ave. Recency| Ave. Frequency| Ave. Monetary| Ave. Spend|
0    0           145118        39.0197       1.7264         14,971.85     8,672.07
1    1           2             47.0          19.0          237,270.00    12,487.89
2    2           1236          15.9716       24.9101       126,992.79     5,098.02
3    3           219847        41.9736       3.0682         17,701.64     5,769.23
4    4           9837          23.9330       3.2735        172,642.35    52,738.42
5    5           64865         24.8281       1.8599         13,159.21     7,075.19
6    6           3855          26.5647       3.9304         54,333.56    13,823.64
7    7           219549        17.7493       3.3356         17,570.67     5,267.52
8    8           34171         23.5205       9.1703         42,136.68     4,594.89
9    9           3924120       24.7933       1.1684          4,754.76     4,069.21
```

I then apply the `rank()` method like this:

```
ranks['r_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Recency'].rank()
ranks['f_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Frequency'].rank(ascending=False)
ranks['m_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Monetary'].rank(ascending=False)
ranks['s_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Spend'].rank(ascending=False)
ranks['overall'] = ranks.apply(lambda row: row.r_rank + row.f_rank + row.m_rank + row.s_rank, axis=1)
ranks['overall_rank'] = ranks['overall'].rank(method='first')
```

Which gives me this:

```
   Cluster  No. Customers|Ave. Recency|Ave. Frequency|Ave. Monetary|Ave. Spend|r_rank|f_rank|m_rank|s_rank|overall|overall_rank
0    0          145118       39.0197      1.7264        14,971.85    8,672.07     8     9       8      4      29        9     
1    1          2            47.0         19.0         237,270.00   12,487.89     10    2       1      3      16        3 
2    2          1236         15.9716      24.9101      126,992.79    5,098.02     1     1       3      8      13        1
3    3          219847       41.9736      3.0682        17,701.64    5,769.23     9     7       6      6      28        7
4    4          9837         23.9330      3.2735       172,642.35   52,738.42     4     6       2      1      13        2
5    5          64865        24.8281      1.8599        13,159.21    7,075.19     6     8       9      5      28        8
6    6          3855         26.5647      3.9304        54,333.56   13,823.64     7     4       4      2      17        4
7    7          219549       17.7493      3.3356        17,570.67    5,267.52     2     5       7      7      21        6
8    8          34171        23.5205      9.1703        42,136.68    4,594.89     3     3       5      9      20        5
9    9          3924120      24.7933      1.1684         4,754.76    4,069.21     5     10      10     10     35        10
```

This does what it's suppose to do, however the cluster with the highest `Ave. Spend` needs to be ranked 1 at all times and the cluster with the highest `Ave. Recency` needs to be ranked last at all times.

So I modified the code above to look like this:

```
if(ranks['s_rank'].min() == 1):
    ranks['overall_rank_2'] = 1
elif(ranks['r_rank'].max() == len(ranks)):
    ranks['overall_rank_2'] = len(ranks)
else:
    ranks_2 = ranks.drop(ranks.index[[ranks[ranks['s_rank'] == ranks['s_rank'].min()].index[0],ranks[ranks['r_rank'] == ranks['r_rank'].max()].index[0]]])
    ranks_2['r_rank'] = ranks_2['Ave. Recency'].rank()
    ranks_2['f_rank'] = ranks_2['Ave. Frequency'].rank(ascending=False)
    ranks_2['m_rank'] = ranks_2['Ave. Monetary'].rank(ascending=False)
    ranks_2['s_rank'] = ranks_2['Ave. Spend'].rank(ascending=False)
    ranks_2['overall'] = ranks.apply(lambda row: row.r_rank + row.f_rank + row.m_rank + row.s_rank, axis=1)
    ranks['overall_rank_2'] = ranks_2['overall'].rank(method='first')
```

Then I get this

```
   Cluster  No. Customers|Ave. Recency|Ave. Frequency|Ave. Monetary|Ave. Spend|r_rank|f_rank|m_rank|s_rank|overall|overall_rank|overall_rank_2
0    0          145118       39.0197      1.7264        14,971.85    8,672.07     8     9       8      4      29        9             1     
1    1          2            47.0         19.0         237,270.00   12,487.89     10    2       1      3      16        3             1 
2    2          1236         15.9716      24.9101      126,992.79    5,098.02     1     1       3      8      13        1             1
3    3          219847       41.9736      3.0682        17,701.64    5,769.23     9     7       6      6      28        7             1
4    4          9837         23.9330      3.2735       172,642.35   52,738.42     4     6       2      1      13        2             1
5    5          64865        24.8281      1.8599        13,159.21    7,075.19     6     8       9      5      28        8             1
6    6          3855         26.5647      3.9304        54,333.56   13,823.64     7     4       4      2      17        4             1
7    7          219549       17.7493      3.3356        17,570.67    5,267.52     2     5       7      7      21        6             1
8    8          34171        23.5205      9.1703        42,136.68    4,594.89     3     3       5      9      20        5             1
9    9          3924120      24.7933      1.1684         4,754.76    4,069.21     5     10      10     10     35        10            1
```

Please help me modify the above if statement or perhaps recommend a different approach altogether. This ofcourse needs to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: Ok so you want a custom ranking on your dataframe, where the cluster(/row) with the highest `Ave. Spend` is always ranked 1, and the one with the highest Ave. Recency always ranks last. Please edit yout code example to be executable (MCVE).

Comment: By the way, just a tip, columns containing spaces are annoying and make the code long, I'd rename them `AvRec, AvFrq, AvMon, AvSpn` or whatever.

Comment: By the way, `rank()` will return float (not int) when applied to a float column. Because  there might be a tie, and `rank(method='average')` returns floats. It's not safe to downcast this with `.astype(int)` because you need to handle those corner-cases.

Comment: As to stating the problem clearly: *"I have a dataframe with my clusters and their key metrics."* Is a 'cluster' a group of customers? (credit-card users? B2B? grocery?) a group of computers? something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a custom ranking on your dataframe, where the cluster(/row) with the highest `Ave. Spend` is always ranked 1, and the one with the highest `Ave. Recency` always ranks last.

The solution is five lines. Notes:

- You had the right idea with `DataFrame.drop()`, just use `idxmax()` to get the index of both of the rows that will need special treatment, and store it, so you don't need a huge unwieldy logical filter expression in your `drop`.
- No need to make so many temporary columns, or the temporary copy `ranks_2 = ranks.drop(...)`; just pass the result of the `drop()` into a `rank()` ...
- ... via a `.sum(axis=1)` on your desired columns, no need to define a lambda, or save its output in the temp column `'overall`'.
- ...then we just feed those sum-of-ranks into `rank()`, which will give us values from 1..8, so we add 1 to offset the results of `rank()` to be 2..9. (You can generalize this).
- And we manually set the 'overall_rank' for the `Ave. Spend`, `Ave. Recency` rows.
- (Yes you could also implement all this as a custom function whose input is the four `Ave.` columns or else the four `*_rank` columns.)

Code: (see at bottom for boilerplate to read in your dataframe, next time please make your example MCVE, to help us help you)

```
# Compute raw ranks like you do
ranks['r_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Recency'].rank()
ranks['f_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Frequency'].rank(ascending=False)
ranks['m_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Monetary'].rank(ascending=False)
ranks['s_rank'] = ranks['Ave. Spend'].rank(ascending=False)

# Find the indices of both the highest AveSpend and AveRecency    
ismax = ranks['Ave. Spend'].idxmax()
irmax = ranks['Ave. Recency'].idxmax()

# Get the overall ranking for every row other than these... add 1 to offset for excluding the max-AveSpend row:
ranks['overall_rank'] = 1 + ranks.drop(index = [ismax,irmax]) [['r_rank','f_rank','m_rank','s_rank']].sum(axis=1).rank(method='first')

# (Note: in .loc[], can't mix indices (ismax) with column-names)
ranks.loc[ ranks['Ave. Spend'].idxmax(), 'overall_rank' ] = 1 
ranks.loc[ ranks['Ave. Recency'].idxmax(), 'overall_rank' ] = len(ranks)
```

And here's the boilerplate to ingest your data:

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

# """Cluster   No. Customers| Ave. Recency| Ave. Frequency| Ave. Monetary| Ave. Spend|
dat = """
0           145118        39.0197       1.7264         14,971.85     8,672.07
1           2             47.0          19.0          237,270.00    12,487.89
2           1236          15.9716       24.9101       126,992.79     5,098.02
3           219847        41.9736       3.0682         17,701.64     5,769.23
4           9837          23.9330       3.2735        172,642.35    52,738.42
5           64865         24.8281       1.8599         13,159.21     7,075.19
6           3855          26.5647       3.9304         54,333.56    13,823.64
7           219549        17.7493       3.3356         17,570.67     5,267.52
8           34171         23.5205       9.1703         42,136.68     4,594.89
9           3924120       24.7933       1.1684          4,754.76     4,069.21 """

# Remove the comma thousands-separator, to prevent your floats being read in as string
dat = dat.replace(',', '')

ranks = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep='\s+', names=
    "Cluster|No. Customers|Ave. Recency|Ave. Frequency|Ave. Monetary|Ave. Spend".split('|'))
```